# PyDev not displaying * character

Tags: pydev

Learning Python and using Oxygen Eclipse with PyDev 7.2. Noticed that when I try a simple multiply 2 * 8 that * is not displayed. After I type * and nothing is displayed, I need to press 8 key twice before 8 is displayed. Other characters are fine. Seems odd that * is not displayed.

Keyboard is fine because * is displayed in Word, Notepad and also in PythonWin.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled Eclipse and PyDev and issue went away and now * is displaying as expected. That was an odd problem

Comment: Great... as a note, Oxygen is a pretty old Eclipse version, so, I'd recommend getting a newer version.